# What is the unit number of $17^{17}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, education

What is the unit number of $17^{17}$? The question concerns students between the ages of 14 and 16.

The possible solution are
**(A)** $1$, **(B)** $3$, **(C)** $5$, **(D)** $7$, **(E)** $9$.

I have searched by induction by trying the first powers of $17^{17}$ to understand what the rule was:

$17^2=28\color{red}{9}$

$17^3=491\color{red}{3}$

$17^4=8352\color{red}{1}$

$17^5=141985\color{red}{7}$

$17^6=2413756\color{red}{9}$

$17^7=41033867\color{red}{3}$

$17^8= 697575744\color{red}{1}$

I have seen that the last digits have a sequence as $\color{magenta}{9317-9317\ldots}$ but I don't understand how to get $9$ which is the last digit of  $17^{17}$ from this sequence. There is an unusual fact that the solution provides this:

The digit of the units of a product is determined only by the product of the digits of the units
of the factors. Thus:

$17^2$ has the same digit of units as $7 × 7$ i.e. $9$;

$17^3$ has the same digit of the units as $9 × 7$ i.e. $3$;

$17^4$ has the same digit as the units of $3 × 7$ i.e. $1$;

$17^5$ has the same unit digit as $1 × 7$ i.e. $7$, which is the same unit digit as $17^1$.

The digit of units of the powers of $17$ thus repeats every $4$ consecutive values of the exponent. Since $17 = 4 \cdot 4 + 1$ the digit of units of $17^{17}$ is the same as that of $17^1$, that is, $7$. And this is **false**,

How, therefore, do I get $9$?

Comment: The important one is $17^4$. Now how $17^{4n}$ ends? And $17^{4\times 4+1}$? (and you are right, it **is** $7$)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I don't know. Sorry. :(

Comment: The answer key which suggests 9 is wrong.

Comment: @TobyMak When I did it with the calculator I got 9; now I did it and it is $827240261886336764177$.

Comment: I was wrong to compute the power. Discussion closed. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you very much.

Comment: @TobyMak Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Why there is a downvote?

Comment: @TobyMak Why there is a downvote?

Comment: Can't tell. The question seems fine. Don't pay too much attention to a single downvote.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I have written down my procedure and solution of the text. Thank you. Now I'm going to reciprocate.

Comment: *"Now I'm going to reciprocate"*. Whatever it may mean, don't do that. upvote/downvote is not a "tit for tat" game, and it's frowned upon here. And the system is able to detect systematic behaviour and to react accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct but calculating the entirety of these powers is unnecessary.
Think of a number with digits:
$a_1a_2a_3\cdot\cdot\cdot a_{n-1}a_n$ as: $$10 \cdot a_1a_2a_3\cdot\cdot\cdot a_{n-1} + a_n$$
We can see that if we multiply through by some number ($17$ in this case) then the first n-1 digits, multiplied by this number will still be a multiple of $10$ and, hence, will have no effect on the last digit of this product. We can conclude that the last digits of:
$$a_1a_2a_3\cdot\cdot\cdot a_{n-1}a_n \cdot 17$$ is the last digit of: $$17a_n$$
We can also use the same reasoning to notice this is equal to the last digit of:
$$7a_n$$
Using this, last digits of $17^n$:
$$17^1 \rightarrow 7$$
$$17^2 \rightarrow 7\cdot7 \rightarrow 9$$
$$17^3 \rightarrow 7\cdot9 \rightarrow 3$$
$$17^4 \rightarrow 7\cdot3 \rightarrow 1$$
$$17^5 \rightarrow 7\cdot1 \rightarrow 7$$
We could keep doing this up to $19$ or we could notice that this sequence is going to loop at intervals of $4$ to deduce:
$$17^{4k} \rightarrow 1 \implies 17^{16} \rightarrow 1 \implies 17^{17} \rightarrow 7$$
This is a shoddy example of something called modular arithmetic. I'd recommend researching this and once you have a very basic understanding of it, this question will be easy to do by considering $17^n\equiv7^n\mod{10}$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, you might want to research Fermat-Euler Theorem which turns the solution into a couple of lines.